# ckeditor.js:219 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

i installed **logical Uploader for ckeditor** in my project and it Was installed without problems. i have following controller :

```
 public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/
    Context _db = new Context();
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(content model)
    {
        _db.tbl_Content.Add(model);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

and my content model:

```
 public class content
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get;set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

my strongly typed Index View:

```
    @model ckeditor.Models.content
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>content</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.text)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.text)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#text').ckeditor();
    });
</script>
}
```

but i don't have ckeditor on my `@html.TextAreaFor()` 
what should i do?
[image]

Comment: Look at the first error in your console - one of your scripts is not being found (check the path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` variable:

```
<script>
    var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/Scripts/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

See documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath).

Comment: thanks but i use it before and still have this error ! what is Default 1 ?

Comment: Based on your screenshot your site or mvc project is called `Default1` and so the URL to the `Scripts` folder is under Default1. I suggest you try to navigate to one of ckeditor files directly in the browser, and when you know the right base path define the `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `Default1` was the name of your controller. The setting should be `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/Scripts/ckeditor/';`

Comment: thanks. but where actually i need to add this script? before loading ckeditor.js or doesn't matter?

Comment: i wrote it before loading ckeditor.js but still have the same error.

Comment: I suggest you check your browser's console again to see the client side errors.

Answer (score 0):

For others with this problem (since it still persists as of the newest version at this time), if you have self-hosted the CKEditor script in your solution (for example for a classic ASP.NET application) and you do not have all the localization files of the plugin in your CKEditor folder, that can cause this issue to happen.

We for example only had the `en.js` file in our `/CKEditor/lang/` folder, and the bug occurred when a user that had both english and danish as his browser languages. CKEditor tried to automatically set the language of the editor to Danish, and tried to load the `/CKEditor/lang/da.js` file, which did not exist (which caused a 404 error). As seen in the original question here, the browser console shows a 404 error trying to load the `/lang/fa.js` language file, but to no avail. Adding the following to the config.js file fixed the problem for us:

`config.language = 'en';`

[setting config.language](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/uilanguage.html) ensures that the language of the editor is set to english instead of it being auto detected.